# Why is C# .NET WebException not being caught in WP7 emulator?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 app, and I need to PUT some data on our company's REST api.

I was testing out this API call, and ran into a WebException that I couldn't catch. My call was originally in a lambda, so I pulled it out into member functions, but still no luck.

The error string is "The remote server returned an error: NotFound". Which isn't unexpected, a URI that my app tries might not be valid either because I screwed up, or because our staging server is down.

How the heck am I supposed to check if my request failed if I can't catch this exception?

Here's my toy example:

```
void TriggerApiCall()
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(
        "http://api.ourcompany.com" +
        "/stuff/" +
        someParameterizedPath + "?" +
        "firstParam=" + someClassMember +
        "&secondParam=8badf00d"));

    request.Method = "PUT";
    request.BeginGetResponse(TryCall, request);
}

private void TryCall(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest;
    var completed = result.IsCompleted;
    WebResponse response = null;
    try {
        bool hasresp = request.HaveResponse;
        response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e); // Never reaches here,
                                               // Exception propagates to top
    }
    response.Close();
}
```

Comment: Does it work on real device? Emulators can't be 100% trusted.

Comment: Unfortunately still waiting for devices + AppHub accounts to go through. I'll be testing this problem and updating this question when we do get it. In the meantime I'd like to know if anyone else has ran into this and possibly found a way around it.

Comment: Just a side note. The `the remote server returned an error. NotFound` error message doesn't necessarily mean that the error was caused because the server was not found. There could be other causes and might be being thrown elsewhere.

Comment: I know that the error is because or a bad URI address and our server throwing a 404. The problem is more the fact that if a call to HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse() fails, then the app crashes and there's nothing I can do about it.

Comment: @bearcdp: Have you added Network capabilities to your WMAppManifest.xml?

Comment: I didn't realize I needed to add Network capabilities to WMAppManigest. We've been using WebClient for GET and POST just fine, but ran into issues using it for PUT and DELETE. Do you have a link for more info on that?

Comment: It's very easy: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769509%28v=vs.92%29.aspx In the capabilities section, you'll want to add `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING"/>` The WMAppManifest file will be in the `Properties` folder of your project.

Comment: Just re-read your comment. Only `GET` and `POST` are supported methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

Comment: Wow. Is there any particular reason they don't support anything but GET or POST? Now we gotta go and ask our backend guys to add support for POST versions of all our DELETE and PUT calls (writing this assuming you still can't create raw sockets in WP7).

Comment: Sockets are available in the Mango toolkit (which you can download now: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=77586864-ab15-40e1-bc38-713a95a56a05&displaylang=en). However, the Mango update won't be released till later this year so you can't submit your apps with it for the time being. Not sure why the other verbs aren't supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Research tells me there's a new ClientHttp stack in Silverlight 3 and above.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd920295(v=vs.95).aspx